# Is it possible to use header ("Location: ...php"); and Section in the same page?

Tags: php

After my code is executed I would like to change page and go to specific section, for example:

code.php

......
header ("Location: ../home.php"); and inside home.php go down to p id="3">

home.php

p id="1">

p id="2">

p id="3">

Thanks in advance

Comment: `home.php#1`? Unclear what you’re asking. Please go read [ask], and how to provide a [mcve].

Comment: just use `#`. Example: `header ("Location: ../home.php#3");`

Comment: Yep you both answered exactly my question, thank you and sorry, im so noob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes You have to use # for example

```
header('location:hello.php#3')
```